# How to create a select list from values 1 AM , 1:30 AM and so on?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, meteor-react

Creating a react app in which I am using a drop down and menu item to create a select list with value 1:00 AM, 1:30 AM and so on till 12:00 AM, next day.

I have created a basic logic and posted it on js fiddle
[Fiddle link with basic logic for select](http://jsfiddle.net/C_Sandeep/T4UXw/47/)

Can we make it better, it working but it's messy, is there any other way

```
$(function(){
    let i = 1;
    while(i <= 24) {
      let amPmCaption = i < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      let timeValue = i <= 12 ? i : i-12;
      $("select").append("<option>" + `${timeValue}: 00 ${amPmCaption}` + "</option>");
      $("select").append("<option>" + `${timeValue}: 30 ${amPmCaption}` + "</option>");
      i++;
    }
 })
```

Is there a better way to achieve this also at the end I am getting 12:00 PM instead of 12:00 AM.

React code for the same is using menuitem and dropdown from the material UI

```
getTimeSlotList() {
    let i = 1;
    let menuItems = [];
    while(i <= 24) {
      let amPmCaption = i < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      let timeValue = i <= 12 ? i : i-12;
      console.log('value of i = ', i);
      menuItems.push(
        <MenuItem key={i} value={i} primaryText={`${timeValue}: 00 ${amPmCaption}`} />,
        <MenuItem key={i*10} value={i*10} primaryText={`${timeValue}: 30 ${amPmCaption}`} />
      )
      i++;
    }
    return menuItems;
}
```

React jsx code is

```
 <SelectField value={this.state.period} onChange={this.updateStartTime}>
    {this.getTimeSlotList()}
 </SelectField>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say you are using material-ui, then I would recommend using a `TimePicker` component with `minutesStep={30}`. See documentation [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/time-picker).

This is likely to be more user friendly than a select.